# How to import a private key in bitcoin-qt?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I've a paper wallet with privatekey which is created using coinbase.com. I want to import it in bitcoin-qt but I don't see an option in bitcoin-qt UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help->Console "importprivkey YOURKEYGOESHERE"